# Modify fontsize of tooltip in DENEB CHART

Tags: json, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, deneb

_Hi, I would like to modify the fontsize of the tooltip of my DENEB CHART but after many tries, no success. Thanks for your help.

[Here is my Pbx file.](https://1drv.ms/u/s!An2aQoxg76Kv8GTTVh81EyUlqJhF?e=S59Mpj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible using the default tooltip in Deneb. The following is a good workaround:

Ensure PBI handles the tooltip:

[image]

Change the font size in PBI.

[image]